# Python - Achar a quantidade de numeros maiores que a media

Tags: python

estou com dificuldade na seguinte questão: 
Escrever uma função em python que receba
como parâmetro uma tupla de reais. A função
deve retornar a média e a quantidade de
valores maiores que a média.

E então eu cheguei no seguinte resultado :

```
def somar_elementos(lista):

     soma = 0

     media = 0

     for numero in lista:

       soma += numero

       media = soma / numero

     return media

a=(5, 10, 6, 8)

print(somar_elementos(a))
```

Porém, não sei como continuar daqui para achar a quantidade de números maiores que a média

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto aqui deve te ajudar:

```
def somar_elementos(lista):
  media = sum(lista) / len(lista)
  return media, len([n for n in lista if n > media])
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que seja isso que você quer.

```
def somar_elementos(lista):

     soma = 0

     for numero in lista:
          soma += numero

     media = soma / len(lista)

     maiores=[]

     for i in lista:
          if i >= media:
               maiores.append(i)

     return media, maiores

a=(5, 10, 6, 8)

print(somar_elementos(a))
```

Answer (score 1):

Além da [resposta do Patrick](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/298378/88991), você pode utilizar outras bibliotecas que podem lhe facilitar a vida.

Neste caso, [Numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/index.html) pode lhe facilitar muito a vida. Basta apenas usar o [numpy.mean](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) e o [numpy.size](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.size.html)

```
import numpy as np.
# Pega a lista como você esta antes.    

def somar(lisnp):

  lisnp=np.array(lista)
  return lisnp.mean(),lisnp[lisnp>lisnp.mean()].size
```

Vale lembrar que este exercícios são interessantes pra desenvolver a sua capacidade. Tente resolver eles sozinhos :D!